# Reading and Writing Images to Isolated Storage

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have come across a couple of different ways to write images to isolated storage on some Windows Phone sites, however I am unsure which is the best to use for a camera app or if there are some that are better than others:

The first is from this post on a basic camera application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202956(v=VS.92).aspx It takes the jpeg from the camera and writes it to isolated storage directly.

```
   void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = savedCounter + ".jpg";

    try
    {   // Write message to the UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Captured image available, saving picture.";
        });

        // Save picture to the library camera roll.
        library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);

        // Write message to the UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Picture has been saved to camera roll.";

        });

        // Set the position of the stream back to start
        e.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Save picture as JPEG to isolated storage.
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the image to isolated storage. 
                while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }

        // Write message to the UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Picture has been saved to isolated storage.";

        });
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close image stream
        e.ImageStream.Close();
    }

}
```

It seems to use a 4kb Buffer, is there any point in doing it this way? Seems a bit more complicated than this method which converts the image to a bitmap then uses the save as Jpeg method (http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images):

```
   // Create a filename for JPEG file in isolated storage.
        String tempJPEG = "logo.jpg";

        // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

            StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative);
            sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
            Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

            //wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

If there are any alternative methods you have also I'd be interested, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Think you should check this out:

I believe I already answered this and got a +50 bounty
 [SO Save image to Isolated Storaged using byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950525/saving-the-photo-to-a-class/8982129#8982129)