# “Unspecified error” when converting a byte array into a BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

My goal is to upload and download images using a web service. I understand that in order to do that the images need to be converted to a byte array. However, I’m getting “Unspecified error” when converting a byte array into a BitmapImage.

I’ve create a test rig that converts an image (from a PhotoChooserTask) into a byte array and back again that recreates my problem. The code that does the conversion is listed below with the problem line highlighted.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{

    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        //Display the photo
        BitmapImage PhotoBitmap = new BitmapImage();
        PhotoBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        Photo.Source = PhotoBitmap;

        //Convert the photo to bytes
        Byte[] PhotoBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
        e.ChosenPhoto.Read(PhotoBytes, 0, PhotoBytes.Length);

        //Convert the bytes back to a bitmap
        BitmapImage RestoredBitmap = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(PhotoBytes);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        RestoredBitmap.SetSource(stream);    //<------ I get "Unspecified error" on this line

        //Display the restored photo
        RestoredPhoto.Source = RestoredBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you check the result of `e.ChosenPhoto.Read(PhotoBytes, 0, PhotoBytes.Length);`? It should return the number of bytes read.

Comment: I checked the result of e.ChosenPhoto.Read() and it returns 0 even though e.ChosenPhoto.Length is 119264 - am I missing something when creating the byte array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time you use `e.ChosePhoto` as source, the stream is read and the `Position` property is advanced to the end. You can inspect the `PhotoBytes` array in the debugger to see that after your read operation it actually does not have any content (or check the return value of the `Read` method to confirm zero bytes are read).

What you need to do is reset that `Position` to zero before you read from it again:

```
//Convert the photo to bytes
Byte[] PhotoBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];

// rewind first
e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;

// now succeeds
e.ChosenPhoto.Read(PhotoBytes, 0, PhotoBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Correct, i do endorse Mister Goodcat, resetting the Position makes it to workfine to fetch the stream data. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that this is what's happening (comments inline):

```
//Display the photo
BitmapImage PhotoBitmap = new BitmapImage();
PhotoBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto); // This is reading from the stream
Photo.Source = PhotoBitmap;

//Convert the photo to bytes
Byte[] PhotoBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
e.ChosenPhoto.Read(PhotoBytes, 0, PhotoBytes.Length); // Fails to read the full stream
                                                      // because you already read from it

//Convert the bytes back to a bitmap
BitmapImage RestoredBitmap = new BitmapImage();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(PhotoBytes); // You're creating a stream that
                                                    // doesn't contain the image
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
RestoredBitmap.SetSource(stream); // Fails because your stream is incomplete
```

`Seek` to 0 in the stream before you attempt to read from it.  And check the return value from the `Read` call to make sure it matches `PhotoBytes.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
//Display the photo
BitmapImage PhotoBitmap = new BitmapImage();
PhotoBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
Photo.Source = PhotoBitmap;
```

uses the Stream of the `e.ChosenPhoto` and might not rewind the Position of the Stream.

So when you do this:

```
Byte[] PhotoBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
e.ChosenPhoto.Read(PhotoBytes, 0, PhotoBytes.Length);
```

you are starting at the end of the stream reading nothing.

Use Seek to reset the Position of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out my other post where I already did this?
I had receive a pretty good rating from it.

[BitmapImage to byte[] and byte[] to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950525/saving-the-photo-to-a-class/8982129#8982129)