# ResourceDictionary replacement from code

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary

I need to download RecourceDictionary from net and connect it to the project.

So in App.xaml I have something like a stub with current ResourceDictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then I am downloading and storing new ResourceDictionary (ResourceDictionary2.xaml) to IsolatedStorage. Then I need to replace the current one with the new one.

In fact IF this another file WOULD BE right in a project folder I would make like this:

```
var newDict = new ResourceDictionary { 
     Source = new Uri("/WP7ResourceDictionaryTest;component/ResourceDictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative) 
};
ResourceDictionary appResources = App.Current.Resources;
appResources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);
appResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newDict);
```

this code works.

So the question is: how to replace current RecourceDictionary with the file which is in IsoStorage?
I tryed to set Uri like this:

```
newDict.Source = new Uri("isostore:/ResourceDictionary2.xaml");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is that -1? What is you suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use my Generic Isolated Storage Utility found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950525/saving-the-photo-to-a-class/8982129#8982129)

Then do the following:

```
ResourceDictionary isoResourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)IsolatedStorage_Utility.Load<ResourceDictionary>(filename);
appResources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);
appResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(isoResourceDictionary);
```

The next problem is you **HAVE** to do this before InitializComponents, because Silverligh/WP7 **ONLY** allows for StaticResources. The only way around this is to refresh your current page.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think it will work with xaml. First line is returning an error "Error in line 1 position 2. Expecting element 'ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ResourceDictionary', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'."

Comment: I guess thats not serializable. Convert it to a byte[] or something first. Look into the XAMLWriter