# Background image is changed to default on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 application, i have created a button to change the default background image and the users can have their own custom skins on the app. It worked perfectly. But when the users exits the app and relaunches it again the application's background image is changed to default. But what i needed is, the application should have the last image that is chosen by the user even is launched no. of times. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

```
private void BackgroundBrowserIcon_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var PhotoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
        PhotoChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(PhotoChooser_Completed);
        PhotoChooser.Show();
    }

    void PhotoChooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                var app = Application.Current as App;

                if (app == null)
                    return;
                var imageBrush = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = bmp, Opacity = 1.0d };
                this.LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
                app.backchanged = true;
                app.appbrush = imageBrush;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using IsolatedStorageSettings to store the last chosen photo, and then loading it on app launch?

**Update:**
Check out this post, as it explains how to code exactly what you are looking to accomplish: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Captured-Image

Comment: No, i don't know how to use IsolatedStorageSettings and i don't know what to do, to store the last chosen photo. Please help me with this!

Comment: Check out the link I posted above in my answer. That should point you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/working-isolated-storage%E2%80%99s) to learn how to store IsolatedStorageSettings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;


namespace F5debugWp7IsolatedStorage
{
   public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
   {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings ISSetting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

       if (!ISSetting.Contains("DataKey"))
        {
            ISSetting.Add("DataKey", txtSaveData.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ISSetting["DataKey"] = txtSaveData.Text;
        }
        ISSetting.Save();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have the image so you can rebind to the background?  Can you save the location of the image?

Comment: Actually by default i have places a some 6 images and the users can also choose their own photo(from photo chooser task). So what i need is, if the user changes the background image, i need my app to remember that background image for the next time the app is launched.

Comment: Try this [article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Binary-files) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950525/saving-the-photo-to-a-class/8982129#8982129) on stackoverflow.