# How to store and get images in IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I want to be able to save images in `IsolatedStorage`, and later get it.

for this purpose I wrote a helper which I want to access it from everywhere in my app:

**for creating an image:**

```
public static void SaveImage(Stream image, string name)
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!isolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("MyImages"))
        {
            isolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("MyImages");
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine("MyImages", name + ".jpg");

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, isolatedStorage))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            sw.Write(image);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("failed");
    }
}
```

**and for getting that image again:**

```
public static BitmapImage Get(string name)
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        var filePath = Path.Combine("MyImages", name + ".jpg");

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, isolatedStorage))
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(fileStream);
            return image;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("failed");
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I try to set source of `image` I get this error message:

> The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

Comment: Check this helpfull answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950525/saving-the-photo-to-a-class/8982129#8982129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the right Capabilities under your `WMAppManifest.xml` what you need is:

```
public static void SaveImage(Stream image, string name)
{

    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(attachmentStream);
    var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
    var temp = new MemoryStream();
    wb.SaveJpeg(temp, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 50);

    using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("MyImages"))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("MyImages");
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine("MyImages", name + ".jpg");

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
        {
            fileStream.Write(((MemoryStream)temp).ToArray(), 0, ((MemoryStream)temp).ToArray().Length);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

That should work and store your image as a jpeg into your desired directory. if it doesn't, make sure that the create directory and `Path.Combine()` methods are being used correctly.